# How to have image set of jquery event?

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

So I am trying to get a picture to set off a jquery Show function. I am failing, I have tried a lot of things to no avail. The jquery documentation wasn't helpful for me :(

This is the jquery, straight off of W3C. This is all I need for what I am trying to do right now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#regi").click(function(){
    $("#reg").show();
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to show, it starts off with visibility:hidden;

```
<div id="reg">
  <image src = "../media/RegPage.png">
    <input type="text" name="usernameReg" value="email" STYLE="position: fixed; top: 175px; background-color: rgb(187,187,187); font-family: 'VT323', cursive;//#9cf;"/>
    <input type="password" name="pwrdReg" value="pass" STYLE="position: fixed; top: 195px; background-color: rgb(187,187,187); font-family: 'VT323', cursive;"/>
    <input type="password" name="VpwrdReg" value="pass" STYLE="position: fixed; top: 195px; background-color: rgb(187,187,187); font-family: 'VT323', cursive;"/>
</div>
```

This is the image. I tried using it as a button and changing the image of the button, wasn't having any luck. Please help. Want it such that clicking this sets off the jquery show event.

```
<image id="show" src="../media/Register.png" ></image>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `image` tag in HTML, you should use `img` tag and it doesn't have closing tag.

```
<img id="show" src="../media/Register.png" />
```

Also note that `show` method doesn't show the elements that have `visibility: hidden` property, you should use `display: none` instead, or use `css` method:

```
$("#reg").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `#regi`?

Try changing it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#reg").show();
  });
});
```

And as @undefined said, change your `image` tag to `img` as there is no `<image/>` tag in HTML.